# Fstream declaration

Tags: c++, fstream

I need to be able to use a function multiple times with a different file. I have this piece of code:

```
fstream in(inf, ios::in);
```

where `inf` is a string with a `.mpp` extension, and it doesn't work (the declaration) 
can you please help me? :)

Comment: @Mark Not that it matters, but Whats' a .mpp for?

Comment: @Tim Microsoft Project, I think. So opening it is not going to do him any good anyway.

Comment: Post the actual error message(s) please.

Comment: @Neil Just wondering, i guess he will have to open it in binary mode  PS. Google proved you right

Comment: Wild guess: missing the `std::` prefix?

Comment: Doesn't compile? Doesn't run? Doesn't find the file? Only works for the first file?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
 fstream in(inf.c_str(), ios::in);
```

Better yet, use an ifstream:

```
string mpp = "foobar.mpp";
ifstream in( mpp.c_str() );
```

I don't understand why people don't use the specialised input and output streams when they only want to perform one of input or output.

Comment: @Mark Then you need to explain your problem more clearly. "doesn't work" is about the worst response you can make here.

Answer (score 0):

As I may infer of your "doesn't work" responses, maybe you have to:

a) Include the `fstream` header.

b) Use `std::` prefix for `fstream` (or `ifstream`)

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::ifstream in (inf.c_str());
```

(note that if you use `ifstream` you don't have to specify `ios::in`)

Answer (score -2):

Hmm.

Maybe try to wrap this function in some file hanlder object. Then just include file handler header in working files and use as much as you like..